# R data string subset values, if condition fulfilled

Tags: r, matrix

I am programming in R and I have the following problem:

I have a matrix a that looks like this:

```
a:  employee1 employee2  team1 team2
        1         5        1
        1         8        1
        2         5        1
        3         9        2
        ...
```

The matrix is quite long, the first row means that employee1 sent a message to employee2. team1 is the column that tells you, in which team employee1 is, team2 tells you, in which team employee2 is.

I have another matrix:

```
b:  employee team
        1      1
        2      1
        3      2
        4      2
        ...
```

This is a matrix tells you, which employee belongs to which team.

I want to fill the column team2 in matrix a. Therefore I have to get the information from matrix b. Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a <- cbind(a, team2 = b[match(a[ , "employee2"], b[ , "employee"]), "team"])
```

Another possibility is:

```
dat <- merge(a, b, by.x = "employee2", by.y = "employee")
```

The second command returns a data frame. You can transform it into a matrix with `as.matrix(dat)`